# Pre-populating a dropdown box with current month and current year

Tags: php

I need to populate a drop down box automatically in PHP, it needs to be formatted in a particular way...

Starting with the current month and current year, then 21 entries displayed with a monthly interval.. Like this....

```
 <select name="date" id="date">
<option value="1/4/2019">April 2019</option> (Current Month Current Year)
<option value="1/5/2019">May 2019</option>
<option value="1/6/2019">June 2019</option>
<option value="1/7/2019">July 2019</option>
<option value="1/8/2019">August 2019</option>
<option value="1/9/2019">September 2019</option>
<option value="1/10/2019">Ocotber 2019</option>
<option value="1/11/2019">November 2019</option>
<option value="1/12/2019">December 2019</option>
<option value="1/1/2020">January 2020</option>
<option value="1/2/2020">February 2020</option>
<option value="1/3/2020">March 2020</option>
<option value="1/4/2020">April 2020</option>
<option value="1/5/2020">May 2020</option>
<option value="1/6/2020">June 2020</option>
<option value="1/7/2020">July 2020</option>
<option value="1/8/2020">August 2020</option>
<option value="1/9/2020">September 2020</option>
<option value="1/10/2020">October 2020</option>
<option value="1/11/2020">November 2020</option>
<option value="1/12/2020">December 2020</option>
```

```
I was looking at doing...

$currentmonth = date("F");
$currentyear = date("Y");

Etc.. But feel there is probably an easier way, any help appreicated
```

Comment: Code from approved answer will generate two marches in 2021(just try to increase number of iterations and check the output), thus it should not be used. Please, check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Versions supported (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)

```
$no_of_iterations = 21;
$time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
echo  "<select name='date' id='date'>";
for($i = 1; $i <= $no_of_iterations; $i++) {
     $date_in = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+$i month", $time));
    echo "<option value='".date("1/m/Y", strtotime($date_in))."'>".date("F Y", strtotime($date_in))."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Sorry just a quick one, I'm currently missing April 2019 from the list, it's starting at May 2019? Instead of current month April?

Comment: I worked it out, I changed "for($i = 1; " to "for($i = 0;" thank you

Comment: Adjust the $time as per the requirement. In the loop it will start from +1 month.

Answer (score 1):

5.3+

```
$d = new \DateTime('first day of this month');
echo  "<select name='date' id='date'>";
for ($i = 0; $i < 21; $i++) {
    $target = $d;
    echo "<option value='".$target->format("1/m/Y")."'>".$target->format("F Y")."</option>";
    $d->modify('first day of next month');
}
echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

so you want to look at strtotime() this allows you to take away one month at a time. Because you want it start on the first you're concatonating on 01 to the start.

See the below snippet...... the comments should explain it enough I hope.....

```
$html = buildDateDropDown();

echo $html;

function buildDateDropDown ( ) {

$FirstThisMonth = "01".date('-m-Y'); //Concatonate 01 tith the month & year of this month


$dropDown = "<select class='form-control' id='date' name='date'>\n";  //open your select tag
$dropDown.="\t<option value='$FirstThisMonth' selected>$FirstThisMonth</option>\n"; //first of this month is selected

$loop=1;

while($loop<=21) {

    $value = "01".date('-m-Y', strtotime('-'.$loop.' month')); //strtotime converts - the loop value of one month
    $dropDown.="\t<option value='$value'>$value</option>\n";    //concatonate in your value
    $loop++; //increment the loop

}

$dropDown.="</select>\n"; //close the select

return $dropDown;
```

}